# linkedin logout function(javascript API) is not working in some conditions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, linkedin-api

In my website, I have provided a facility to login via linkedin. I have used javascript API for that.
I have written below code for login.

```
function onLinkedInAuth() {
    var isLoggedIn = document.getElementById('<%=hdnIsLoggedin.ClientID %>').value;
    // Check for the session on the site
    if (isLoggedIn == false || isLoggedIn == 'false') {
        IN.API.Profile("me")
          .fields("id", "firstName", "lastName", "industry", "emailAddress")
          .result(function (me) {
              //debugger;
              var id = me.values[0].id;
              var fname = me.values[0].firstName;
              var lname = me.values[0].lastName;
              var industry = me.values[0].industry;
              var email = me.values[0].emailAddress;
              // AJAX call to register/login this user
              jQuery.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "UserRegisterAsSeeker.aspx/LinkedinLoginOrRegister",
                  data: "{id:'" + id + "',fname:'" + fname + "',lname:'" + lname + "',email:'" + email + "'}",
                  contentType: "application/json; Characterset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: true,
                  success: function (data) {
                      closeLoginWindow();
                      __doPostBack('<%=lnkRefreshPage.UniqueID%>', '');
                  },
                  error: function (request, status, error) {
                      alert('Unable to process the request at this moment! Please try again later.');
                  },
                  complete: function () {

                  }
              });
          });
      }
}
```

Above code works fine.
And for logout i have used below function provided by linkedin

```
function logout() {
        IN.User.logout(function () {
            window.location.href = '/logout.aspx'; 
        });
    }
```

Problem is in logout. When we login to the site and immediately logout, it works fine but when we leave the site ideal for some time it does not logout from linkedin. We have to click 3-4 times then it works.

I don't know why it's happening. Please help if you can.

Comment: Are there any errors generated when you click and nothing happens? Anything in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Actually that logout function callbacks and control redirected to logout.aspx page as well, but it doesn't loggedout from linkedin, so according to my login code, it again loggedin to my site. But let me comment my href code in callback and check for any error in console.

Comment: @PaulMennega: Meanwhile you can check this issue on our live site http://qms2.asentri.com/index.aspx

Comment: @PaulMennega: I have checked & found that the logout function stuck at https://secure-us.imrworldwide.com/cgi-bin/m?ci=us-603751h&cg=0&cc=1&si=https%3A//www.linkedin.com/uas/connect/logout%3Foriginal_referer%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A52470%252FMyCollaboration.aspx%26token%3DwleiEbuad58BtsMYM6iNf2hQDdCZqgAjO_La%26isFramed%3Dfalse%26lang%3Den_US%26oauth_token%3Dtc0TToyn2HP0XfD-cajtEX3yp1myfkWxTYDp%26api_key%3Dov530jys69jd%26callback%3D%257BCALLBACK%257D%26_ts%3D1347601304505.4453&rp=https%3A//platform.linkedin.com/js/xdrpc.html%3Fv%3D0.0.2000-RC1.20888-1402&ts=compact&rnd=1347601307688

Comment: Looks like a problem/conflict with [imrworldwide](https://www.google.ca/search?q=imrworldwide&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which appears to be some kind of server-side spyware that is blocking the call LinkedIn.